# Get the list of all possible numpy array column deletions

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

Given the following numpy array:

```
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

How can get the list of all possible column deletions? So in this case:

```
array([[[1, 2],
        [4, 5],
        [7, 8]],

       [[0, 2],
        [3, 5],
        [6, 8]],

       [[0, 1],
        [3, 4],
        [6, 7]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations`:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> np.array([a[:, list(comb)] for comb in combinations(range(a.shape[1]), r=2)])

array([[[0, 1],
        [3, 4],
        [6, 7]],

       [[0, 2],
        [3, 5],
        [6, 8]],

       [[1, 2],
        [4, 5],
        [7, 8]]])
```

Comment: I was looking for a numpy indexing method, but I will accept this answer if nothing else comes up

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create a list of needed column indices first and then use [integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) to pick up the required columns from the original array:

```
r = range(a.shape[1])
cols = [[j for j in r if i != j] for i in r]  

cols
# [[1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1]]

a[:, cols].swapaxes(0, 1)

#[[[1 2]
#  [4 5]
#  [7 8]]
#
# [[0 2]
#  [3 5]
#  [6 8]]
#
# [[0 1]
#  [3 4]
#  [6 7]]]
```